# Improve/mute privilege notifications for elected moderators

Tags: feature-request, privileges, moderators, achievements-dialog

Yesterday evening, I was [elected](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/4) as a ♦ moderator on English Language Learners. Today, I got my first upvote on the site since then, and the achievement inbox showed that I gained three new privileges:

[image]

Wouldn't it make more sense to either

1. not show these notifications at all (I'm a moderator, I'm supposed to know I have them), or
2. show these when a CM flips the 'isModerator' switch on my user (or perhaps after accepting the mod agreement)?

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks!